# Getting campaign code from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, campaign

Is there an easy way to extract all the campaign code and the campaign name from Marketing Cloud? I'm surprised it's not part of the query which we could extract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no data view or standard extract, but you can get the list of all Campaigns and their associated attributes - Code, Name, Colour etc from the REST API's [/hub/v1/campaigns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getCampaignCollection.htm) route. The response looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
{
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 2,
    "count": 2,
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/v1/campaigns?$page=1&$pagesize=2&$orderby=Name ASC&$orderBy=Name+Asc"
        },
        "next": {
            "href": "/v1/campaigns?$page=2&$pagesize=2&$orderby=Name ASC&$orderBy=Name+Asc"
        }
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "301",
            "createdDate": "2012-11-29T16:18:31",
            "modifiedDate": "2012-11-29T16:18:30",
            "name": "2012 Master Campaign",
            "description": "This is the Primary Campaign",
            "campaignCode": "master2012",
            "color": "d2e7b8",
            "favorite": false
        },
        {
            "id": "310",
            "createdDate": "2012-11-29T16:18:31",
            "modifiedDate": "2012-11-29T16:18:30",
            "name": "East Coast",
            "description": "East Coast Only",
            "campaignCode": "EASTCOAST",
            "color": "d2e7b8",
            "favorite": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, if you want to understand which emails etc are associated with a given campaign, you'd use the [/hub/v1/campaigns/{id}/assets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getCampaignAssetCollection.htm) route to retrieve all the "assets" used in the Campaign:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
{
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "totalCount": 3,
    "entities": [
        {
            "id": "20",
            "campaignId": 330,
            "type": "TRIGGERED",
            "objectID": "1bef7d61-cb0b-e111-bb7b-1c659d025f52",
            "createdDate": "2012-12-19T14:49:23"
        },
        {
            "id": "19",
            "campaignId": 330,
            "type": "AUTOMATION_DEFINITION",
            "objectID": "5e8baeea-1cf8-4c84-bf09-655a66afa2d5",
            "createdDate": "2012-12-19T14:49:23"
        },
        {
            "id": "17",
            "campaignId": 330,
            "type": "EMAIL",
            "itemID": 7888,
            "createdDate": "2012-12-19T14:49:23"
        }
    ]
}
```

The "itemid" in this response is the EmailID as it appears in your _Job Data View that's accessible through Query Activity. To get all this data in Data Extensions, you'd need to write something like an SSJS Activity for Automation Studio.

Comment: Thanks Andrew... That was what I read online too... I thought there's an easier way since I am not really a developer or a programmer kind of guy.

Comment: My rates are very reasonable ;) Try asking Support if there's a "Custom Extract" that would be suitable for this. It's the sort of thing they may have already done for another customer. You may get lucky.

Comment: I'm sure "reasonable" can means expensive :) I've asked support and they asked me to ask around in forum or pay the account executive to instruct their developer build for us.

Comment: You're right, my rates aren't very reasonable, but I have many mouths to feed :-s Account Execs tend to have one very hungry mouth and no kids who can do anything for you any time soon. If you have any developers in-house, try to get them to take a look. Aside from the above, there's the minor stuff of setting up credentials for the API. The rest of what's required should be pretty standard stuff and not at all SFMC specific for a developer.

Comment: Following up on this... finally i manage to learn on extracting the campaign code via REST API :) But somehow i'm stuck with only one page of the results. I read the docs and it says i can add "page" parameter to it but doesn't seems to get beyond page 1 and only 50 rows. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi James. You have a few parameters you can manipulate within the URL to the REST endpoint, "$page", "$pageSize" and "$orderBy". The maximum number of records you can stipulate for $pageSize is fifty. Where there are more than fifty records available to retrieve, you'll see there's a links.next property returned that contains the URL of the next page of results (see example above where there is a page 2) - https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns?$page=2&$pageSize=50&$orderBy=Name ASC

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I will give it a try again. I remember adding the page parameter but even it says the count is 155, I only manage to get page 1 with 50 results. Will let you know my results later.

Answer (score 3):

I wish it was.  The only thing that I've found is the `CampaignID` in the *Sent* file in a [**Tracking Extract**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/extract_types_reference/).

Comment: Thanks Adam. I think the CampaignID and Campaign Code in my case are different. :(

Comment: I think each Campaign Codes are assigned CampaignIDs behind the scenes, if I'm remembering correctly.  I think I had to poke around in the page source to determine that.